# how to create table for specific account using sqlite in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, facebook-sdk-4.0

I created a table to store data in Android Studio using Sqlite. I use Facebook SDK to create an account through Facebook and store some data of application, not Facebook data, for that account and then display it. But when I logout and login again with another account then previous data is still there.

I want to store different data for different accounts, so when when user logs in again his data will be there.

Question is: how to do it? Should I create an another table to store Facebook account details? And if yes then how to link the data table with specific account?

Answer (score 0):

To do this relatively simply but without that much security add a column to the table(s) to hold (or represent) the account. The when you access the data include a condition (WHERE clause) to only select rows for the account.

Consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fb_account_data_simple;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fb_account_data_simple (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fb_data TEXT, fb_account TEXT);
INSERT INTO fb_account_data_simple (fb_data, fb_account) VALUES
    ('Face Book Data 001','FRED'),
    ('Face Book Data 002','FRED'),
    ('Face Book Data 001','MARY'),
    ('Face Book Data 003','MARY'),
    ('Face Book Data 004','MARY'),
    ('Face Book Date 003','FRED');
;
SELECT * FROM fb_account_data_simple WHERE fb_account = 'MARY';
```

This;

- creates a table called **fb_account_data_simple** that has two columns 1 for the data and 1 for the face book account name.
- It then loads 6 rows of data 3 rows for each account.
- Lastly it extracts just the rows for the account named MARY resulting in :-

[image]

However the above is not normalised as the same account name is stored multiple times.

A normalised version would have a table for the account and a column in main table that references the account.

For example consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fb_account;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fb_account (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, account TEXT);
INSERT INTO fb_account (account) VALUES
    ('FRED'), -- will very likely have an _id value of 1 automatically generated by SQLite
    ('MARY')  -- will very likely have an _id value of 2 automatically assigned by SQLite
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fb_data;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fb_data (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, fb_data TEXT, account_reference INTEGER);
INSERT INTO fb_data (fb_data, account_reference) VALUES
    ('Face Book Data 001',1),
    ('Face Book Data 002',1),
    ('Face Book Data 001',2),
    ('Face Book Data 003',2),
    ('Face Book Data 004',2),
    ('Face Book Date 003',1);
;
SELECT fb_data, account 
    FROM fb_data
        JOIN fb_account ON account_reference = fb_ACCOUNT._id
    WHERE account = 'MARY'
```

This;

- creates a table for the face book accounts
- then it loads the two accounts.
- then it creates the table for the data
- then it loads some data for both accounts (using the unique id of the row for the account)
- it then extracts the data from the data table and gets the respective data from the account via a **JOIN**

The end result is the same (as far as the data that is useful to the end user):-

[image]

Although this does seem more work for the same result, it is considered the better method as it's more efficient (numeric keys/indices are generally faster to traverse and use less storage and therefore have reduced i/o overheads)

If you wanted the data to be secure then that's a more complex issue but quite feasible.

Comment: i need explanation of second method, how to add account reference?

Comment: and also remember that we are displaying all data from table in listview , but we dont need to show any reference or account name ,

Comment: 1 When use has logged in then you have the account (id and all the account specific data e.g. name). When you have new data then you store the data along with the id that reference the account. To not show sets of values e.g. account name just omit the row so all data could be to change `SELECT fb_data ....` (i.e. account has been dropped. from the query) .